# Spring unable to start embedded tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I try to follow this tutorial: [Using WebSocket to build an interactive web application](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/#scratch).

I use eclipse, debian10, maven 3.6, jdk1.8, tomcat8.

After importing the git project I want to run the "complete" folder. However I get the following error:
`org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server [...]`

I did not edit anything so I am really confused where this error might come from.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the entire stack trace and any relevant code or a [mre] if applicable.

Answer (score 2):

If the port is already used, you could simply change the port by adding this line to `application.properties`:

```
server.port=8081
```

[Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-port)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the port 8080 was already in use.
I solved the issue by simply changing the port of the spring boot application like this

edited MessagingStompWebsocketApplication.java

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MessagingStompWebsocketApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MessagingStompWebsocketApplication.class);
    app.setDefaultProperties(Collections.singletonMap("server.port","8089"));
    app.run(args);
  }
}
```